# How do I get jQuery autocompletion in TypeScript?

Tags: jquery, typescript

If I'm working in a TypeScript .ts file, what can I do to get jQuery Intellisense/autocompletion when I type the $ character?

(I'm working in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project in VS 2012.)

Comment: I want the same but I am not on windows, I got the syntax highlighting but how can I setup the autocompletion for any other program that is not running in windows?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the jQuery definition at the top of your `.ts` file.

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

You can find type annotations for jQuery [in this sample](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d397c54a55db#samples/jquery/jquery.d.ts).

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was missing.

Comment: Is there a global location where this file can be placed to enable to be referenced from anywhere?

Comment: Is jquery.d.ts provided by JQUERY or custom. If custom, how do we update and keep sync with new version of JQUERY?

Comment: @Myagdi: For now this is a manual process. Also don't be surprised if there are bugs in the definitions, it's hard to get this right. Anyway, I bet that once TypeScript takes off it will have a way to link from a JS file to a `.d.ts` and JQuery will be doing that.

Comment: Is not this very wired to use `///` at the start of the line!? It will comment the line!

Comment: @Wavum Yes, I know that. I meant when they were making the compiler, they could choose a better format for importing .d.ts files

Comment: @M98 You can also use the [import syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html) which is prettier imo

Comment: I have found that if you have the package installed via `npm install` the autocomplete seems to function well for .js files without issue. Via the reference key `F12` the d.ts file can be found to have been loaded under appdata like this: `\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\2.6\node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts`. I find however, that if I put a .ts file in the directory, this breaks and direct inclusion must occur via `///`. The appdata path does work at this point.

Answer (score 41):

Check out these type definitions for TypeScript: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped#readme.
They're being updated regularly and are more complete than the ones in the examples.
On Nuget: http://www.nuget.org/profiles/DefinitelyTyped/

Comment: Are these the same definition files as the nu-get packages?

Comment: You can do npm install --save-dev @types/jquery or @types/whatever for other packages too

Answer (score 14):

Checklist of things that need to be set up for this to work:

1. Ensure the TypeScript extension is installed. Check Tools -> Extension Manager and make sure "TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio" extension is installed. If it isn't, run the .vsix file found in the TypeScript folder (Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\<version>) to install the extension.
2. Ensure your file references the jquery.d.ts file. You should have a comment at/near the top of your file that looks like this:

> /// <reference path="the/path/to/jquery.d.ts" />

If you need to download it, you can find the jquery.d.ts file as part of the Warship sample at http://www.typescriptlang.org/Samples/

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to use jQuery in the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/).