# TypeScript and libraries such as jQuery (with .d.ts files)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I've looked all over the internets but I have yet to find a comprehensive guide that tells me how to take a library such as jquery and use it in a TypeScript project.  If there is a guide that exists I would love to know where otherwise these are the things I really need to know:

1. I understand that the .d.ts file is only for intellisense so what do I need to get jquery to actually work (compile to ts?)
2. Do I need a `requires` or a `//reference` when using VS2013 and if so what is that actually doing?
3. Anything to go from these .d.ts and jquery js files to using the library (or any library) in my ts project.

I've been able to figure pretty much everything else out but this one has been rather frustrating.

Comment: Oh, and this is also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682028/how-do-i-get-jquery-autocompletion-in-typescript?rq=1

Comment: Again, this is useful only for non-Visual Studio users looking to get intellisense to work.  I have intellisense working and would like to get the library to work!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to compile jquery to typescript, you just need to use a definition file that tells Typescript how the JavaScript library works.

Get definitions here:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

or from NuGet if using Visual Studio.

Then just write your typescript as normal, and declare your library if needed:

`declare var library : libraryTypedName`

for example jquery's d.ts file already does this for you (check the bottom):

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jquery

Now in your `.ts` file when you type `$` it should give you the typescript intellisense.

Now the only things you want to include in your bundleconfig / `<script>` are the .js files, both yours and jquery / other libraries. Typescript is COMPILE time only!

Comment: I have that .d.ts and I get this error:
Unhandled exception at line 1, column 1 in ms-appx://io.cordova.ohdh/www/js/game.js

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

Comment: I had scr="jquery-2.1.1-min.js"! But this is really helped me understand what was happening and why, thanks!

Comment: ..."and declare your library if needed:", can you say why? If this happens do you mean in a d.ts that represents the lib getting written?

Comment: @CRice that is for libraries that don't already do it for you, most of them do if you use definitelytyped or another definition source. If you have a more specific question you might want to start a new question :)

Comment: how do you import jquery

Comment: @John declare module did no work in visual studio, what is the use

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan you might want to make a new post to list your issue with code examples :)

Answer (score 11):

The convention in TypeScript is to have a `reference.ts` or `reference.d.ts` file in your project that will bring in these external references.

So in your `reference.ts` file add the path to your `jquery.d.ts` (the path will be relative to the reference.ts file):

```
/// <reference path="../relative/path/to/jquery.d.ts"/>
```

Then you should be able to use the jQuery definitions in your project.

*NOTE: The reference.ts file is a convention but you can actually add a `<reference path="..."/>` directive to any TypeScript file if needed.*

---

From the [TypeScript Language Specificiation (PDF)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) 11.1.1:

> A comment of the form `/// <reference path="…"/>` adds a dependency on the source file
>   specified in the path argument. The path is resolved relative to the directory of the containing
>   source file.

Comment: That only works for autocomplete/intellisense but doesn't actually give me the functionality of the library.  I want to actually use the library!  Maybe this is super simple but I'm still rather lost. And just fyi, this is no longer necessary in Visual Studio.  It automatically does that for all .d.ts files.

Comment: Then just include jQuery on the page. The .d.ts tells TypeScript what jQuery provides as interfaces and types, then it's up to jQuery to actually provide the implementation.

Comment: Also, since I posted this answer, there is the new `@types` project which lets you do `import * as $ from 'jquery'` and get proper type information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Answer (score 7):

I am using it in VS 2015, and I am new to typescript.I used jQuery and leaflet in my project.  My solution is:

1. Download all these libraies from NuGet manager in VS 2015.
   [image]
2. Drag the library files (.js) as instructed in this tutorial:

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/

3. Modify the index.html file by adding these lines.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />

   <script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   <script src="scripts/leaflet-0.7.3.min.js"></script>
   ```
4. Modify the index.ts file. First add these lines on top to reference your libraries. You may need to change the path.

   [image]
5. Add your won code within onDeviceReady(), otherwise you might get javascript runtime error, like sysmbol "$" is not defined. I guess this is because the codes try to load some function when the device is not ready yet. This has worked for me. Hope it would help you too.

   ```
       function onDeviceReady() {

       document.addEventListener('pause', onPause, false);
       document.addEventListener('resume', onResume, false);


       var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
       var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
       var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
       listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
       receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

       // your code goes here

       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

this solution is not for typescript purists :), but if you prefer one line solution, just add this line to your .ts file:

`declare var $: any`

and then use `$` anywhere in your typescript code as if you were in js code.

Comment: What's the point of typescript if you type it as `any`? :D (even for non-purists)

Comment: more than often, it is not you who made the decision to use typescript and you just need to get things done in an existing codebase.