# Using jQuery plugins inside Typescript file

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm using typescript for the first time in my company projects, and I have this JS file:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap-switch.d.ts" />    
function CreateIdeSkuValidoSwitch() {
     $("[name='actived_ideskuvalido']").bootstrapSwitch();
}
```

But when I will use this in my Typescript function, the compile say: property does not exist on type 'jQuery'.

I want to know, how I use this jQuery plugin switch inside my ts files with jQuery.

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: Pretty sure TS just compiles JS. Try referencing the path to the compiled JS file instead of the TS file. I might be wrong, especially since its friday.

Comment: @Devilscomrade When I did that, I see: Cannot resolve referenced file:

Comment: Really confused, if `jquery.d.ts` and `bootstrap-switch.d.ts` exist in the same directory, this error should not be happening unless neither definition file was found. Do you get an error if you have code like `$("[name='actived_ideskuvalido']").html('hello')`?

Comment: @JuanMendes HTML ok, because this function has inside jQuery, but bootswitch doent exist inside jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using jQuery plugin in TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719529/using-jquery-plugin-in-typescript)

Comment: If the d.ts file exists, and the reference path is correct, tsc should compile just fine. Check that the reference paths are correct. IIRC reference paths are relative.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear; however, from your comment "imagine if I have use the plugin that doesn't have .ts file" it seems like you are asking: How can I use a jQuery plugin that doesn't already a `.d.ts` definitions file.

The reason jQuery is defined in TypeScript is because are using a jQuery definitions file. That file tells TypeScript that `$()` is a function that returns an object with the known jQuery functions.

If you create a new plugin, you should create a `.d.ts` file that will let users of your plugin reference your code from TypeScript.

If you use a plugin that doesn't have a TypeScript definition file, you have to create a definition yourself, or you can cast your jQuery object to `any`. The first option is much better because the IDE and the compiler will still help you.

Let's say you create a new plugin that replaces the content of the object with the words "Hello World";

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.helloWorld = function() {  
      this.html('Hello World');
      return this;
    }
})(jQuery);

// Either the plugin author provides the definition, or you write them yourself
interface JQuery {
    helloWorld();
}
```

TypeScript allows you to define an interface multiple times, combining it with previous definitions, so the above definition won't overwrite the existing definition.

See [Using jQuery plugin in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719529/using-jquery-plugin-in-typescript)

And [here's an example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20X%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20some%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20X%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20hello%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20arr%3A%20Array%3CX%3E%20%3D%20Array.from%3CX%3E(%5B%7B%20some%3A%201%2C%20hello%3A%202%20%7D%5D)%20%2F%2F%20no%20error%0D%0A%0D%0A) that shows that you can add behavior to existing interfaces

[Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped) is a resource maintains definition files that allow you to use regular JavaScript libraries from your TypeScript and it has a number of definition for popular jQuery plugins

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bootstrap-switch/bootstrap-switch.d.ts the `jQuery` type is extended with the `bootstrapSwitch` method, so, if the reference is correctly added to the stack, you shouldn't have problems...

Comment: I'll try, but, the question is, imagine if I have use the plugin that doesn't have .ts file.

Comment: @soamazing Is your question how to use a plugin in TypeScript that doesn't already have a typescript definition in a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: probably here is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540165/typescript-and-libraries-such-as-jquery-with-d-ts-files