# How to reference jQuery (intellisense) in a typescript file (VS2015)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have a lot of javascript plugins and libraries in my ASP.NET MVC project,
 that I want to convert to typescript.

**Questions:**

**How to reference jQuery in ts files?**

I get this error below when I manually build the ts file using `tsc`

> myfile.ts(170,4): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'jQuery'.
>   myfile.ts(172,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
>   myfile.ts(173,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.

Comment: q2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540165/typescript-and-libraries-such-as-jquery-with-d-ts-files

Comment: I have [downloaded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37738610/2581562) a definition jquery definition file and referenced it in my .ts file, this works without erros, but compile on save for ts files does currently not work yet...

Comment: While there is some conceptual overlap between the Visual Studio settings and what's in a `tsconfig` file, they have different scopes and purposes. You absolutely need a `tsconfig` file for any project that has more than a dozen files and for an AMD (RequireJS) project of even the smallest imaginable size.

Comment: I've added the tsconfig, set AllowJS to false, in order to limit the error output to only a few lines, I get a lot of bunch of "Duplicate ..." errors..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Install [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) if you haven't already
2. Open the command line (cmd.exe)
3. `cd` to your project root directory
4. Execute `npm install @types/jquery`

Now under node_modules you will find the "index.d.ts" typescript definition file for jQuery.

> node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts

5. Drag and Drop the file on the top of your opened typescript file "yourFile.ts"

> /// <reference
>   path="../../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
>   
> ....
>   
> ... your typescript code here

Now you will have intellisense for **jQuery** and **$**.