# jQuery not recognized in Typescript files

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm working with a web api project involving typescript. It's not recognizing the jquery symbol $ in the typescript files. Google says all I have to do is this:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

It doesn't work.

I know this depends on package.json being available. What does package.json have to look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript and libraries such as jQuery (with .d.ts files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540165/typescript-and-libraries-such-as-jquery-with-d-ts-files)

Answer (score 2):

If this is a Visual Studio project that doesn't have npm set up, there are a couple of other ways to do this. The best is probably to install the NuGet package jquery.form.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped, which will add the file /Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts (at least on a classic ASP.NET project, not sure about Core.)

Another thing you can do is tell TypeScript to let you use $ without checking anything:

```
declare var $: any;'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your `@types/*` are registered in your tsconfig.json. 
Like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

Another idea is to use `import * as $ from 'jquery';`