# How to use jquery in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic3

I'm trying to load external website in a div using jquery in ionic 3.

**TS:**

```
export class HomePage 
{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {    
      $('#loadExternalURL').load('http://www.google.com');
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="loadExternalURL"></div>
</ion-content>
```

I'm getting blank screen on serving the ionic app. Is there anything I'm missing? Any Suggestion?

Comment: is there any console log?

Comment: Are you including jquery library?

Comment: @Luke Log console is empty.

Comment: @Walk Yes I have included jquery library.  Used following commands to install jquery library npm install jquery --save and typings install dt~jquery --global --save

Comment: look at this  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/use-ionic-with-jquery/1120/12

Answer (score 18):

I did it in following way,

1. Install Jquery module in your IONIC-3 app,

   **npm install jquery --save**
2. Import JQuery in HomePage.ts

   **import * as $ from "jquery";**
3. Use $ to call jquery methods.

I wait for method ngAfterViewInit to make sure view is initialized.

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('JQuery is working!!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Might want to install the typings as well.

Answer (score 10):

To use jQuery in ionic project do it this way:

Install the Jquery module in your IONIC-3 app as follows:

```
1, npm install jquery --save
2, npm install @types/jquery
```

then import jquery on your page like this

```
3, import * as $ from "jquery";
```

You can then use the jquery $ as you would in normal javascript. I have used it for a jquery ajax call to get remote data like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "my api url",
    method: "POST", //you can do post, get, put
    data: my-data
}).done(function(res){
     //process response from server
}).fail(function(err){
     //return error message.
});
```

It worked very fine.

Comment: Yes, it needed to ensure all the necessary dependencies are met to use jquery seamlessly in your ionic 3 application without issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to import jQuery into your project somehow. If you want to use HTML you need to add it near the top of your page

```
<script src="[path to jQuery source]"></script>
```

Or use a .d.ts file defining jQuery

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

then define it where needed

```
<reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

References used:

[TypeScript and libraries such as jQuery (with .d.ts files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540165/typescript-and-libraries-such-as-jquery-with-d-ts-files#26541175)

[How do I get jQuery autocompletion in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12682028/how-do-i-get-jquery-autocompletion-in-typescript?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You not need to use jQuery

You can add iframe

```
<div>
    <iframe src="yourexternalpage url"></iframe>
</div>
```