# Importing jQuery-dependent library in ionic 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic3

I'm trying to import external JavaScript file (which uses jQuery) to my ionic 3 project.

**To install jQuery**, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823909/how-to-use-jquery-in-ionic-3) answer, I ran:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Then I can see that jQuery is working by executing some code inside `$(document).ready` from the first page of my app (it works).

Now I need to include reference to my external jQuery library, which I've done in `src/index.html` by:

```
<script src="assets/js/myLibrary.js"></script>
```

**myLibrary.js uses jQuery by:**

```
(function($, window, document) { 
...
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

But unfortunately I get `jQuery is not defined` error from the library file.

I'm not sure if jQuery is not yet ready or something else, I tried adding `defer` attribute to the script import but with no luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using Ionic-Angular. Does your project have a main imports file like src/app/main.ts? My project imports and bootstraps platformBrowserDynamic() here.

Comment: It imports `build/main.js`, `vendor.js` and 'polyfills.js' - before importing my custom imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting jquery in `src/assets/jquery.min.js`, and then in `index.html` I added a script reference before the jQuery-dependent library I wanted to use:

```
<script src="assets/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
<script src="assets/js/myLibrary.js" defer></script
```

I'm not sure if that's the correct way to do this in ionic, and I'm not sure if that makes a duplicate import of jQuery [I already imported it via `npm install jquery --save`].

Anyway it works - FYI for anybody looking in this thread in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this in your html file. Please note that you can only do that when you have wifi.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Isn't that makes duplicate import of jQuery? If I already told ionic to have jQuery by `npm install jquery`, why can't I just use it straightforward?

Comment: I dont know ive never used that away I always only use the link or download the file manually